# How to make a details page for every db item with its ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that contains a list of items 
every item have an action link that redirect to the page of the item

the view :

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="card text-white bg-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 400px;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="@ViewBag.Path" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">@item.ArticleTitle</h4>
                    <a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Article", "Article", new { Controller = "Account", Action = "SignIn", id = item.ArticleID })'" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">إقرأ المزيد »»</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

the resault of this action link is /Article/Article/4
As 4 is the db item id

the other view which have to display every item detail page :

```
@model IEnumerable<ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData>

<h2>@Html.DisplayNameFor(mode => mode.ArticleTitle)</h2>
<img src=@ViewBag.Path style="max-width:40%;max-height:400px;" />
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticleText)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArticlePostDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticleText)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArticlePostDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("EditArticle", "Article", new { id = item.ArticleID }) |
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Article", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Article", new { id = item.ArticleID })
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

the controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Article(int ArtID)
        {
            using (MatrodyEntities db = new MatrodyEntities())
            {
                db.NewsData.Find(ArtID);
                return View("Article", ArtID);
            }

        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Articles()
        {
            List<NewsData> articles = new List<NewsData>();
            using (MatrodyEntities db = new MatrodyEntities())
            {
                var type = new NewsData();
                articles = db.NewsData.Where(xn => xn.ArticleID == type.ArticleID).ToList();
                ViewBag.Count = db.NewsData.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.NewsData").Count();
                return View(from NewsData in db.NewsData.ToList() select NewsData);
            }
        }
```

after this everytime when i go to a link like this Article/Article/4
it doesn't work and it shows me this error message :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ArtID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Article(Int32)' in 'ElMatrodySite.Controllers.ArticleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters
>
> System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ArtID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Article(Int32)' in 'ElMatrodySite.Controllers.ArticleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

RouteConfig :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ElMatrodySite
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows that error message because `ArtID` is null

Comment: change  public ActionResult Article(int ArtID) to  public ActionResult Article(int id) and also correct the <a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Article", "Article", new { Controller = "Account", Action = "SignIn", id = item.ArticleID })'" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">إقرأ المزيد »»</a>
to <a onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Article", "Article", new { id = item.ArticleID })'" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">إقرأ المزيد »»</a>

Comment: What is the use of this line of code `articles = db.NewsData.Where(xn => xn.ArticleID == type.ArticleID).ToList();` cause you are not using anywhere articles

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel I did as you said and it gives me that error message

`
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData]'.
`

Comment: @GabrielCostin It shows a list with the db items in the first view i mentioned above

Comment: @kingkomand2o Man you are returning a view with different data then articles so unless you have not posted all code , that line of code has no purpose in that action method

Comment: @GabrielCostin which code i have to post all of it ?

Comment: @kingkomand2o Make it clear which code is part of which view and so on , cause we do not have access to your solution in Visual Studio but we see only this part of code and is hard to understand what you trying to achieve and how

Comment: This is an issue with your routing configuration. The third parameter in `/Article/Article/4` gets mapped to `{id}` not to `ArtID`. If you could show us your routing configuration, we could understand better. In your case, change the `ArtID` parameter in your Edit and Delete methods in your controller to `id` and then try running your code.

Comment: @kingkomand2o just rename variable name int ArtID to **int id**.

Comment: @RahulSharma I have replaced all this ArtID with id and it still gives me an Error message
`

Comment: @kingkomand2o Please show us your `RouteConfig.cs` so we can understand better what could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @RahulSharma Done.

Comment: @kingkomand2o Try adding a new rule in your `RouteConfig.cs`: `routes.MapRoute(
            "GetArticle",
            "Article/{ArtID}",
            new { controller = "Article", action = "Article" });`

Comment: @RahulSharma it gave me another Error message `System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData]'.
`

Comment: @kingkomand2o Yes this is because you are returning `ArtID` in your View and your View requires a model of type:`ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData`, therefore in your `Article` method, return something like this: `var modelData=db.NewsData.Find(ArtID); return View("Article",modelData);`. I am assuming that you get a List of type `NewsData` when you call your db.

Comment: @RahulSharma I made this id parameter equals both of the prop in model and the column in database `public ActionResult Article(int id)
        {
            using (MatrodyEntities db = new MatrodyEntities())
            {
                var data = new NewsData();
                data.ArticleID = id;
                db.NewsData.Where(xx => xx.ArticleID == id);
                return View("Article",id);
            }

        }`

Comment: @RahulSharma and also i edited the route config to be like this "Article/{id}" and it also did'nt work

Comment: @kingkomand2o I think you are missing out on my point. You are again returning `id` back to your model whereas your models requires a `IEnumerable<NewsData>`, therefore you have to send your List to the model and not your id.

Comment: @RahulSharma thank you soooooooooooooo much i made a list for the viewmodel and it works

Comment: @RahulSharma but i need something else , how can i make the list take the article by id or by the firstOrDefault method ? the new code for the detail action result : `
        public ActionResult Article(int id)
        {
                List<NewsData> oneList = new List<NewsData>();
                var data = new NewsData();
                db.NewsData.Where(xx => xx.ArticleID == data.ArticleID);
                data.ArticleID = id;
                return View(from NewsData in db.NewsData.ToList() select NewsData);
            }

        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to be specific to your case the first issue lies in how you have defined your route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

You can do either of these two things:

1) Change your parameter name in your ActionResult if you are using the default route config:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Article(int id)
{
  using (MatrodyEntities db = new MatrodyEntities())
  {
    db.NewsData.Find(ArtID);
    return View("Article", id);
  } 
}
```

2) Add new route for Article:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //Add your route here
    routes.MapRoute(
     "GetArticle", 
     "Article/{ArtID}", 
     new { controller = "Article", action = "Article" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

Once you have done either of these two methods, then you are getting a `System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData]` error.

This error basically means that you are returning an incorrect model to your View. In your case your View expects a model of type: `IEnumerable<ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData>` but you are returning back `return View("Article", ArtID);` which is incorrect and hence you see this error.

To resolve this, you would have to send a model of type that your View expects. In your case it is a `List<NewsData>`.

Finally, you have asked that how to use `FirstOrDefault()` in your case. You use `FirstOrDefault()` when you are not sure whether your specified criteria will return a record or not from your Collection. Now I am not quite sure if I have the full code for your ActionResult method here but you can add the `FirstOrDefault()` like this:

```
public ActionResult Article(int id)
{
    List<NewsData> oneList = new List<NewsData>();
    var data = new NewsData();

    //Return the first element that matches the specified criteria or null if nothing is found
    data=db.NewsData.Where(xx => xx.ArticleID == data.ArticleID).FirstOrDefault();

    data.ArticleID = id;
    return View(from NewsData in db.NewsData.ToList() select NewsData);
}
```

Based on your criteria, you can do additional error checking. If you want to handle a case where no value is returned from `FirstOrDefault`, you can check for it like:

```
if(data== null)
{
do something
}
```

Comment: one more single issue , in the details view page do i have to use `IEnumerable` in the `@model` or just type it like that : `@model ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData` ?

Comment: @kingkomand2o You would have define it as `IEnumerable<ElMatrodySite.Models.NewsData>` since you are returning a `List<NewsData>` to the View.